# Conversion from decimal to negabinary and vice versa in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, converting, integer

Recently I set about to writing conversion functions in Haskell between decimal and [negabinary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negabinary). I tried to write them in as much functional a style as possible, also aiming at brevity. Below I present my take at the task. I'd be interested in your refinements of the method I employ or any comments whatsoever.

These are my two functions for converting back and forth:

```
type NegaBinary = String

dec2negbin :: Int -> NegaBinary
dec2negbin = reverse .
             map intToDigit .
                 unfoldr (\x -> if x==0 then Nothing else Just(abs(xrem x (-2)), xdiv x (-2)))
    where
      xrem a b = if b > 0 then rem a b else (-(rem a (-b)))
      xdiv a b = if b > 0 then div a b else (-(div a (-b)))

negbin2dec :: NegaBinary -> Int
negbin2dec = sum . map (\x -> (snd x)*(-2)^(fst x)) . zip [0..] . reverse . map digitToInt
```

I defined the `NegaBinary` type just for clarity. The `dec2negbin` employs the `unfoldr` function for sequential divisions and remainder calculations. I also used two local functions: `xrem` and `xdiv`, because the standard functions (`rem` and `div`) had the undesirable behavior of always approaching the dividend from below (meaning that in `div a b => c` `b*c` is always lower than `a`). What I wanted is for it to approach in the direction *from* zero, so the behavior is different for positive and negative dividends. I know the definition of `dec2negbin` is a bit bulky, so improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things I noticed:

xrem and xdiv are exactly the same except they use a different division function. You could therefore replace them with a single function that takes the type of division as a parameter:

```
dec2negbin :: Int -> NegaBinary
dec2negbin = reverse .
             map intToDigit .
                 unfoldr (\x -> if x==0 then Nothing else Just(abs(doDiv rem x (-2)), doDiv div x (-2)))
    where
      doDiv division a b = if b > 0 then division a b else (-(division a (-b)))
```

In your second function you could use [zipWith](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3azipWith) which applies a given function whilst zipping instead of doing a zip then a map:

```
negbin2dec :: NegaBinary -> Int
negbin2dec = sum . zipWith raise [0..] . reverse . map digitToInt
    where
        raise e x = x * (-2) ^ e
```